# Counting variables per observation per month in Sas

Tags: count, variables, sas

a quick question, I have data of the following sort:

Ticker **_ Date _** Fem Analyst (dummy 1 if true) ___ Variables of that month like beta

AA **_ 01/04/2001 _** 1 ___ 0.61

AA **_ 05/04/2001 _** 1 ___ 0.62

AA **_ 08/04/2001 _** 1 ___ 0.63

AA **_ 01/05/2002 _** 1 ___ 0.7

AA **_ 04/05/2002 _** 1 ___ 0.71

AA **_ 08/07/2002 _** 0 ___ 0.8

AA **_ 07/04/2003 _** 1 ___ 0.4

and so on.. What I want to receive is the following:

Ticker **_ Date**  Number of fem analyst  **Number of Male Analysts _** Total ___Variables

AA **_ 04/2001**  3  **0 _** 3 ___ 0.63

AA **_ 05/2002**  2  **0 _** 2 ___ 0.71

AA **_ 07/2002**  0  **1 _** 1 ___ 0.8

AA **_ 04/2003**  1  **0 _** 1 ___ 0.4

So a counting algorithm that allows me to count the number of female and male analyst for a certain company per month( using dummy variable gender 0 or 1) and deletes all observations for that month except the most recent one (for instance for 08/04/01 this becomes 04/01 with 0.63 which is the most recent observation for beta for 04/01 for company AA) The example explains it all I guess?

Any ideas?

Comment: My bad, didn't really thought of that. Went through my questions and checked every valid answer!

Answer (score 1):

You may want something like this:

```
/* Create the month variable into a string YYYY/MM */
data analysts0;
    set <your data>;
    format month $7.;
    month=cats(year(date),'/',put(month(date),z2.));
run;
/* Sort so you can do the by processing required for counting */
proc sort data=analyst0 out=analyst1;
    /* You need to include the date in the sort so the most recent is last */
    by ticker month date;
run;
/* Count */
data count;
    retain n_fem n_male 0;
    set analyst1;
    by ticker month;
    if first.ticker of first.month then do;
        n_fem=0;
        n_male=0;
    end;
    else do;
       if gender=1 then n_fem+1;
       else if gender=0 then n_male+1;
       else put 'Huh?';
    end;
    /* this outputs only the values you need.*/
    if last.ticker or last.month then output;
run;
```

This should give you the general idea - I don't have access to SAS right now so I can't check the code. See the documentation for retain and by processing in the data step for more details.

Comment: Ugh, this string is a little bit difficult for me.

I tried:

data analyst0;
    set final;
    format month $7.
    month=cats(year(recdats),'/',put(month(recdats),z2.));
run;

with recdats being of the type date9 "21jan2001" and "final" the data set.

I get an error though: ERROR 85-322: Expecting a format name.

ERROR 76-322: Syntax error, statement will be ignored.


This is what my data looks like: http://i40.tinypic.com/2d2iwy.png


Cheers though!

Comment: @John, it seems that I've missed some semicolons... I'll edit the answer.

Comment: @John, I modified the code slightly. There is one missing semicolon in the code you provided in the comment, the format statement should be: format month $7.; Also, I think the cats function is only available on SAS 9, so you might want to replace it with trim(left())-calls if cats is not available to you.